# Check if <div data> exists, if exist delete it

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hi guys so I'm trying to run from backend in PHP where if the front-end has a div data for example

```
<div data-mark="" data-mark-top-left="">
<a target="_blank" href="https://google.com">
<img src="https://googlepic.png">
</a>
</div>
```

I would like to remove the whole div data-mark

So far I've tried

```
(Method 1)
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
echo  "$('#divID[data-mark]').remove()";
echo "</script>";

(Method 2)
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
echo  "$('#data-mark').remove();"
echo "</script>";
```

But it didn't work

Comment: `$('#divID[data-mark]')` looks for an element with **id=divID** and has **data-mark** attribute, and `#data-mark` looks for a element with **id=data-mark** ... what you want is `[data-mark]` or `div[data-mark]`

Comment: Hey man, just want to clarify things is the <div data-mark> above, the data-mark is a class or id?

Comment: neither - it's an *attribute*

Comment: So without a class or id attached to that attribute i can't remove it? the parent of that div has a id so i tried getting that parent div id and remove the attribute but it doesn't work

Comment: I just showed you what you need to have in your selector ... `$('[data-mark]')`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're trying to remove the html with jQuery. This has nothing to do with PHP.

```
<script>
$( 'div[data-mark]' ).remove();
</script>
```

Comment: Just in case its late at where you are from.... The backend is written in PHP and i'm using jquery to remove the html id/class, try to process it does it make any sense to you now? Else I don't even have to echo lol

Comment: ok, so this i a javascript/jQuery question. `#` is a id selector in javascript so if you have `<div id="myidgoeshere"></div>` then it can be removed with `$('#myidgoeshere').remove();`.

Comment: Yeah the thing is i cant look for the ID or class therefore I tried to get the parent id to remove the data-mark but still doesn't work but if there is an ID or class in that div it will be much easier

Comment: @AnonyGummy then the `$( 'div[data-mark]' ).remove();` syntax should work. You can do stuff like `$( 'div[data-mark]!=""' ).remove();` or `$( 'div[data-mark]="something"' ).remove();` as well.